# Python Split : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, split

I'm trying to fix this code from yesterday but no more ideea's. The format in c.txt it's DATA:DATA . Can you tell me whats wrong in my code and how i can make it works ?

```
def eml():
    return random.choice(list(open('c.txt'))).split(':')

user = {
    "rr": '84000',
    "descr": desc(),
    "pr": '8400'
}

browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#ctl00').send_keys(user['email'].split(' ')[0])
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#ctl00').send_keys(user['email'].split(' ')[1])
```

Comment: I get the following error now  :   return random.choice(open('c.txt').split(':'))
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Try `random.choice(open('c.txt').read().split(':'))`

Comment: It's works . But now i have another problem `pcr = "%s%s%s"(user["email"],user["rr"],user["pr"])
 f = open('m.txt', 'a')
 f.write(pcr+"\n")
 f.close()`  I get this `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: `"%s%s%s" % (user["email"],user["rr"],user["pr"]) `

Comment: It's work this one but it's write me just DATA1. How i can make it to write DATA1:DATA2 ? I've tryed to add user['email'].split(' ')[1] / user['email'].split(' ')[0] but i get syntax error. And 1 more thing.  It's there any way to take a line from "c.txt" and after it's writed on "m.txt" removed from "c.txt" ? Thanks for help.